# How to defend against xss?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm making a CTF, which is a competition where you have to get a flag using certain methods. I'm working on a problem where they get the flag by using XSS to alert a javascript variable. However, XSS is not safe, and I can't have an XSS problem like that on my website where anyone could do stuff I wouldn't want them to do. **My question is: Is it possible to defend against bad attacks but allow some attacks so that my CTF problem is successful.** Some inputs that I'd like to leave are like `alert(flag)`

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/challenge.css">-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="text"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary submitButton"></button>
        <p id="result">Result</p>
        <script>
            var flag;
            $.get("[website]/cgi-bin/challenge.py", function(data) {
                flag = data;
            });

            var value;
            $(".submitButton").on("click", function() {
                value = $("#text").val();
                $("#result").html(value);
            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `$.get()` just gets a string like `"text"` from a python file and stores it in the variable flag. I replaced the actual website with [website]. If necessary, I can put the website back.

Comment: You could embed the insecure content in an iframe so that it has it's own browser context separate from your secure website.

Comment: all i see there is wrong usage of `.html` that could not result in the ransom type of xss. where is the challenge?

Comment: Thanks Jake. GottZ you put text in the input, and it then uses jQuery to make another <p> element what you said. If you type <h1>test</h1>, it'll make test as an <h1>. If you type <script>alert(flag)</script>, it'll tell you the flag. The challenge is to get that. If that's what you meant by challenge. The problem is if I allow this xss, then they could do all kinds of stuff on my secure website.

Comment: Jake wouldn't that still allow them to do anything on my secure website. I don't really know xss, but I've been told that if it's connected to my website, it is dangerous. If I used an iframe, wouldn't it still be connected to my website?

Comment: XSS attacks requires a server to store user's input, and to serve it later on. It is, the attacker *injects*  malicious code that the server will naively serve and the victim will naively execute. Here there is no user input going to your server and hence no XSS even possible. You're safe. But note that if to defeat your CTF all it needs is to read a clear text Response from the Network Panel or even just type `flag` in the Browser's console, then your CTF will be quite deceptive for a lot of players...

Comment: @Kaiido just want to point out that there are a few types of XSS vulnerabilities. The one you described is referred to as stored XSS. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting

Comment: @Pablo I was also referring to reflected ones, yes I should probably not have used "to store", but when I wrote that comment I had on mind that even if not stored on disk, it is still stored in memory at least the time the response is made. And for type0 if I'm not mistaken, it is more an human factor that would be at risk, for which the only defence would be teaching.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido. I just realized the problem you said about my ctf. I'm working on fixing that.